# In liferay market place, I am unable to submit the project

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

In Liferay market place i am stuck at the place "Upload Liferay Plugin Packages " When ever i am trying to upload a war file [image: This Error]

Please help me to short it out :)

Comment: It complains about file name format. Check their legit' needed name format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Google search for "liferay plugin package file name format" reveals this page:

[Marketplace basics - Development | Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/de/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/marketplace-basics-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-11-en)

And there you can find:

> WAR file names must conform to the following naming convention:
>
> context_name- plugin_type -A.B.C.D.war
>
> Where:
>
> - context_name - Alpha-numeric (including - and _) short name of your app. This name is used as the deployment context, and must not duplicate any other app’s context (you’ll be warned if you use a context name of any other app on the Marketplace).
> - plugin_type - one of the following: hook, layouttpl, portlet, theme, or web.
> - A.B.C.D - The 4 digit version of your WAR file. 4 digits must be used.

So you have to add the version to your file.

Answer (score 0):

Version is missing from your file name. Please add it(version) to your war file.

For example :

```
fileupload-portlet-1.0.0.0.war
```